# iterative through records in sqlserver 2005 to format the output

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

i have  an table  images  with  columns like this and  datalike this

now  i need  to  show data  like this when i run the  Query

```
id  maintitle subtitle  imagename
  1  ram       raman     abc.jpg
  2  manu      kiran     a2.jpg
  2  manoj     kumar     a3.jpg
  2  chiru     kumar     a4.jpg
  3  anu       anitha    a4.jpg
  3  anupam    aruna     a4.jpg
```

need  to  check the id  if it  exits  more than one   row it it  exists then take the  2

row  image name  add a new   column and  display like this  here the

need  output like this

```
 id  maintitle subtitle  imagename  imagename2 imagename3
  1  ram       raman     abc.jpg     null       null
  2  part1     kiran     a2.jpg      a3.jpg     a4.jpg
  3  anu       anitha    a4.jpg      a4.jpg     null
```

ex: i have an data like this

```
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (2,'manu'  ,'kiran' ,'a2.jpg')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (2,'manoj' ,'kumar' ,'a3.jpg')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (2,'chiru' ,'kumar' ,'a4.jpg')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (2,'manu'  ,'kumar' ,'a5.jpg')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (2,'manoj' ,'kumar' ,'a6.jpg')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (2,'chiru' ,'kumar' ,'a7.jpg')
```

here i have  6 rows so i have  to create  six columns . if it has 4 rows then for columns should be created dynamically hope my Question is clear

can any one tel me how  to  solve this

any solution  would be great

Comment: Your output doesn't match your input. Where is part1 in your output coming from? Why would 3 be *anu* and not *anupam*. We could guess these things but it would be easier to just mention it.

Answer (score 2):

your sample data is not consistent with your sample output.  this code uses your sample data, try this:

```
DECLARE @YourTable table (id int, maintitle varchar(10), subtitle varchar(10), imagename varchar(10))
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (1,'ram'   ,'raman' ,'abc.jpg')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (2,'manu'  ,'kiran' ,'a2.jpg')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (2,'manoj' ,'kumar' ,'a3.jpg')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (2,'chiru' ,'kumar' ,'a4.jpg')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (3,'anu'   ,'anitha','a4.jpg')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (3,'anupam','aruna' ,'a4.jpg')

;WITH YourTableOrdered AS
(SELECT
     *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id,imagename, maintitle,subtitle) AS RowNumber
     FROM @YourTable
)
SELECT
    t1.id,t1.maintitle,t1.subtitle,t1.imagename
        ,t2.imagename AS imagename2
        ,t3.imagename AS imagename3
    FROM YourTableOrdered                t1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN YourTableOrdered t2 ON t1.id=t2.id and t2.RowNumber=2
        LEFT OUTER JOIN YourTableOrdered t3 ON t1.id=t3.id and t3.RowNumber=3
    WHERE t1.RowNumber=1
```

OUTPUT:

```
id          maintitle  subtitle   imagename  imagename2 imagename3
----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
1           ram        raman      abc.jpg    NULL       NULL
2           manu       kiran      a2.jpg     a3.jpg     a4.jpg
3           anu        anitha     a4.jpg     a4.jpg     NULL

(3 row(s) affected)
```

---

**EDIT** based on OP's question edit mentioning many/unknown number of files per id.

you have three options:

**1)** code a fixed query with more than enough `LEFT JOINS` like:

```
;WITH YourTableOrdered AS
(SELECT
     *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id,imagename, maintitle,subtitle) AS RowNumber
     FROM @YourTable
)
SELECT
    t1.id,t1.maintitle,t1.subtitle,t1.imagename
        ,t2.imagename AS imagename2
        ,t3.imagename AS imagename3
        ,t4.imagename AS imagename4
        ,t5.imagename AS imagename5
        ,t6.imagename AS imagename6
        ,t7.imagename AS imagename7
        ,t8.imagename AS imagename8
    FROM YourTableOrdered                t1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN YourTableOrdered t2 ON t1.id=t2.id and t2.RowNumber=2
        LEFT OUTER JOIN YourTableOrdered t3 ON t1.id=t3.id and t3.RowNumber=3
        LEFT OUTER JOIN YourTableOrdered t4 ON t1.id=t4.id and t4.RowNumber=4
        LEFT OUTER JOIN YourTableOrdered t5 ON t1.id=t5.id and t5.RowNumber=5
        LEFT OUTER JOIN YourTableOrdered t6 ON t1.id=t6.id and t6.RowNumber=6
        LEFT OUTER JOIN YourTableOrdered t7 ON t1.id=t7.id and t7.RowNumber=7
        LEFT OUTER JOIN YourTableOrdered t8 ON t1.id=t8.id and t8.RowNumber=8
    WHERE t1.RowNumber=1
```

**2)** get the max number of files per a single id and then build up a dynamic SQL statement containing that number of joins.  use this to get the max number of files:

```
DECLARE @MaxFiles  int
SELECT
    @MaxFiles=MAX(CountOf)
    FROM (SELECT
              id,COUNT(*) AS CountOf
              FROM @YourTable
              GROUP BY id
         ) dt
```

**3)** combine all the file names into a comma separated list in a single column, like:

```
DECLARE @YourTable table (id int, maintitle varchar(10), subtitle varchar(10), imagename varchar(10))
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (1,'ram'   ,'raman' ,'abc.jpg')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (2,'manu'  ,'kiran' ,'a2.jpg')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (2,'manoj' ,'kumar' ,'a3.jpg')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (2,'chiru' ,'kumar' ,'a4.jpg')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (2,'manu'  ,'kumar' ,'a5.jpg')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (2,'manoj' ,'kumar' ,'a6.jpg')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (2,'chiru' ,'kumar' ,'a7.jpg')  
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (3,'anu'   ,'anitha','a4.jpg')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (3,'anupam','aruna' ,'a4.jpg')    


;WITH YourTableOrdered AS
(SELECT
     *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id,imagename, maintitle,subtitle) AS RowNumber
     FROM @YourTable
)
SELECT
    t1.id,t1.maintitle,t1.subtitle
        ,STUFF(
                   (SELECT
                        ', ' + t2.imagename
                        FROM @YourTable t2
                        WHERE t2.id=t1.id
                        ORDER BY t2.id,t2.imagename,t2.maintitle,t2.subtitle
                        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                   ).value('.','varchar(max)')
                   ,1,2, ''
              ) AS imagenames
    FROM YourTableOrdered t1
    WHERE t1.RowNumber=1
    ORDER BY t1.id
```

OUTPUT:

```
id          maintitle  subtitle   imagenames
----------- ---------- ---------- -------------------------------------------------
1           ram        raman      abc.jpg
2           manu       kiran      a2.jpg, a3.jpg, a4.jpg, a5.jpg, a6.jpg, a7.jpg
3           anu        anitha     a4.jpg, a4.jpg

(3 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: thanks  for the Replay  i have an issue here the  rows values for the same id can be  Dynamic so there i have  to create n number of columns  based on the  row